# Como agregar un Checkbox al inicio de cada fila en un datagridview en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#

Así cargo datos a mi `DataGridView`

```
using (SqlConnection cn = Claseconexion.ObtenerConexion())
{
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
      SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_CONSULTACOBROS", cn);
      adaptador.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
      adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OPERACION", SqlDbType.Int);
      adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@OPERACION"].Value = 1;    
      adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FILTRO", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@FILTRO"].Value = txtidentificacion.Text;    
      adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FILTRO2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@FILTRO2"].Value = txtreferencia.Text;    
      adaptador.Fill(dt);
      dtgv.DataSource=dt;
}
```

como debo hacer para poder agregarle un `CheckBox` adelante a cada fila?
y como podría ejecutar una acción en el dado caso de que se pulse sobre el `CheckBox`. algo como: si el `CheckBox` de la primera fila es chequeado `txttotal.text=..` a un campo de la linea seleccionada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si defines las columnas en `diseño` indicando la propiedad `DataPropertyName` de las columnas con los campos del `origen de dato` puedes definir una del tipo `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ejecutar una accion hay varias formas de hacerlo, la mas simple es usar el evento `CellValueChanged` o el `CellContentClick`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Solo se trabaja ante los cambios en la columan de los checkbox 
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "NombreColCheckBox") {

        // Se toma la fila seleccionada
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        // Se selecciona la celda del checkbox
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cellSelecion = row.Cells["NombreColCheckBox"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        //resto codigo
    }
}
```

Aqui explico mas completo

[[DataGridView] – Uso del CheckBox - DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/04/datagridview-uso-del-checkbox.html)